# Flutter GetX upload image file not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

I am using Flutter `GetX` for state management. Also, I am using the `GET/POST` method of GetConnect for API calls. I am having trouble uploading image files making `POST` request.

I have created form data as below:

```
  final _formData = FormData({
      'passport_image': MultipartFile(_galleryFile, filename: 'passport.jpg', contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
      'sim_image': MultipartFile(_galleryFile, filename: 'sim.jpg', contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
      'signature_image': MultipartFile(_galleryFile, filename: 'signature.jpg', contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
      'id': 593
    });
```

My post method is as below:

```
  Future<Response> postData(String uri, dynamic body) async {
    try {
      Response response = await post(uri, body, headers: _mainHeaders);
      print("----->" + response.body.toString());
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
    }
  }
```

When I make the API call the form data is not being sent. What am i missing here?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I don't think that's even a good answer for his question to start with... only because a video says so doesn't mean it is a global statement. Problem could even be related to the way he implemented the code, not even the state management package he's using

Comment: It's a direct response to "I am using Flutter GetX for state management."  Which one should generally avoid.

Answer (score -2):

It looks like you're trying to upload image files using the GetConnect library in Flutter, but there are a few issues in your code. First, you are trying to send the same _galleryFile for multiple file fields. Each file field should have its own MultipartFile. Secondly, you should use the MultipartFile.fromFile constructor to create MultipartFile objects from files on your local system.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```
final _passportFile = File('path_to_passport_image.jpg');
final _simFile = File('path_to_sim_image.jpg');
final _signatureFile = File('path_to_signature_image.jpg');

final _formData = FormData({
'passport_image': MultipartFile.fromFile(_passportFile.path, filename: 
'passport.jpg', contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
'sim_image': MultipartFile.fromFile(_simFile.path, filename: 'sim.jpg', 
 contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
'signature_image': MultipartFile.fromFile(_signatureFile.path, filename: 
'signature.jpg', contentType: "multipart/form-data"),
'id': '593' // Assuming 'id' is a string
});

Future<Response> postData(String uri, FormData formData) async {
 try {
Response response = await post(uri, formData, headers: _mainHeaders);
print("----->" + response.body.toString());
return response;
 } catch (e) {
return Response(statusCode: 1, statusText: e.toString());
}
}
```

In this updated code:

I've created separate File objects for each image file.
I use the MultipartFile.fromFile constructor to create MultipartFile objects from the local files.
The FormData object now contains these separate MultipartFile objects for each image.
When calling the postData function, you should pass the FormData object you've created.
Make sure to replace 'path_to_passport_image.jpg', 'path_to_sim_image.jpg', and 'path_to_signature_image.jpg' with the actual file paths to your image files. Additionally, ensure that _mainHeaders contains the necessary headers for your API request.

Comment: Tried using your code snippet but fromfile is not being imported. Does it need a seperate package installation?